# returning a null value instead of no value

Tags: sql-server, syntax

Why are the last 2 selects (cases 5 and 6) returning a null value? This may seem like a trivial question but it actually caused a bug in one of my joins where I expected rows to be filtered out by cross applying to some value and instead it returned the row with a null value.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #temp;
CREATE TABLE #temp (t VARCHAR(1));
```

Cases 1-4 return expected "no value" result.

```
-- CASE 1
SELECT *
FROM #temp;

-- CASE 2
SELECT (SELECT t)
FROM #temp;

-- CASE 3
SELECT (T)
FROM #temp;

-- CASE 4
SELECT CAST(value AS VARCHAR(MAX))
FROM STRING_SPLIT('t', ',') s
WHERE EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM #temp
        WHERE t = 't'
        );
```

Problem cases - returning "`NULL`".

```
-- CASE 5
SELECT (
        SELECT value
        FROM STRING_SPLIT('t', ',') s
        WHERE EXISTS (
                SELECT 1
                FROM #temp
                WHERE t = 't'
                )
        );

-- CASE 6
SELECT (
        SELECT T
        FROM #TEMP
        );
```

Comment: Because the bottom two are sub-queries. Since the table doesn't have any rows, it returns NULL for that sub-query. You are stating for this column, use this value... that value doesn't exist since there aren't any rows, thus NULL

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your last 2 SELECTs are without a FROM clause. These will always return a single row of scalar values.
The fact that the subquery did not return any rows, caused the expression to be NULL - unknown.
Think about the following statement - how would you expect the engine to handle this:

```
 SELECT 1 AS FirstCol, (<some SELECT that returns no rows>) AS SecondCol
```

Note: This is a non standard T-SQL extension. In Oracle for example, you need to add the `FROM DUAL` or you will get `ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected`. However, this same statement with `FROM DUAL` added run in Oracle will also result in a single row of scalar values.

Comment: Try this for example: `SELECT 1 AS FirstCol, (SELECT 1 WHERE 1 = 0) AS SecondCol;`.

Comment: @SQLRaptor - Just to check - in Oracle, if you added `FROM DUAL` to your sample statement, would you get the result set `1, NULL` as you would in SQL Server if you ran the statement as shown?

Comment: @RDFozz Check for yourself - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/304da/1/0